# Publishing to ProGet and I can't see any packages

Tags: nuget-server, proget

I'm trying to set up a NuGet server using ProGet and am hitting a brick wall when publishing a package and it doesn't appear in the feed. The package is written to disk and works in other NuGet feeds. Other packages also don't appear in the ProGet feed so I'm pretty certain that the package is fine and that the problem lies with ProGet.

I'm using the community version of ProGet, but I don't see why that would affect anything.

Any ideas are most welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ProGet service is responsible for indexing packages, so if it's not running, packages could be uploaded but not displayed in any feeds. Here are the common troubleshooting steps for this scenario:

- Verify that the ProGet Windows service (INEDOPROGETSVC) is running.
- Ensure that the user account hosting the ProGet service has access to the feed storage path. Since it is NETWORK SERVICE by default, it would not see your mapped drives, and may not have access to the UNC path where the packages are stored.
- Try running the ProGet service interactively, i.e. stop the ProGet Windows service and run ProGet.Service.exe manually as a console application to see any live output. Remember to restart the ProGet service when you close the console application.
- Check for feed indexing errors to see if there was a problem indexing a particular packages. I know in much older versions that single "poisoned" packages (bad .nuspec file, invalid directory structure, etc.) could halt the indexing altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks John Rasch, found that your first point gave me what i needed to look in the right direction.

I could not find the (INEDOPROGETSVC) service but I did find (ProGet Servie) - I restarted this and then refreshed the my feed and all the missing packages showed up.

My version of ProGet is v3.3.12

Thanks John.